# Azure Security Center missing updates

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-security

Using Azure Security Center and I have most of my VMs showing an informational warning regarding their System Updates.   When I go into them, they don't have any recent data.   There is recent data for the OS Vulnerability column, so I know the connection is working, but this data isn't showing up.

What is the mechanism used to scan these for updates?   Do I need Windows Update service to be started and Automatic, or anything like that?  All my VMs are Windows 2012 or 2012R2, including the few that do appear to be working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the mechanism used to scan these for updates? Do I need
>   Windows Update service to be started and Automatic, or anything like
>   that?

Azure VM needs to update by enabling the Update in the VM or manually. This works just like how your local machine works.

Azure Security Center provides **a quick view** into the security posture of your Azure and non-Azure workloads, enabling you to discover and assess the security of your workloads and to identify and mitigate risk. **It cannot updating your VM**.

Comment: Right.   I'm not expecting it to perform the update.   I'm just wanting the scan data to appear correctly in Azure Security Center.  I'm just getting a blue question mark icon and neither the "OK" checkmark or the "Warning" triangle.   Just having no data there provides no value at all to me.

Comment: Hi,@Chris . Azure Security center can just provider a monitor to check many resources security . That may be useful when we have to ensure many resources to be safe.  If this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answer to help more people. With regards!

Comment: No.   It's not helpful to tell me what ASC is.   The problem here is that it is not performing one of the functions it is supposed to perform.  I have multiple VMs that are under ASC monitoring, but the scan data for System Updates is unavailable.   I'm asking what I should check to figure out the fix.

Comment: Here's an example from one of the machines in question.  What could cause the scan data for System Updates to not be available?                      

System updates       Microsoft (Last scan time - No recent data)
OS vulnerabilities     Microsoft (Last scan time - 11/14/2017 4:40 PM)
Endpoint protection  System Center Endpoint Protection

Comment: Hi,@Chris. This comment is about another question, I suggest you could post a  new question in forum.

Comment: What are you talking about?   this is clearly about the same thing as the initial question...